# Checked checkbox in li tag must be clicked twice to uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, checked

Could someone please help me, how to stop checkbox being checked twice when inside an li with a click event? I tried to add e.stopPropagation function, but it did not work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Obor
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Automotive   </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Automobily   </li>
    <li class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Nákladní auta    </li>
    <li class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Autobusy </li>
    <li class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Prodej ojetých vozů  </li>
    <li class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Komponenty   </li>
    <li class="small" data-value="option7" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Alternativní pohony  </li>
            </ul></li></ul></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var options = [];
$( '.dropdown-menu .small' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }
   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `options` represents the `checked` checkboxes, and it's empty (even though all of your checkboxes are checked).
To fix this you should put inside the `options` variable the values of all the `li` parents of the checked checkboxes.

You can use this to do so:

```
options = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).parent('li').data('value')
}).get();
```

Here is how it will look in your code:

```js
var options = [];
options = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() {
  return $(this).parent('li').data('value')
}).get();

$( '.dropdown-menu .small' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }
   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Obor
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Automotive   </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Automobily   </li>
        <li class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Nákladní auta    </li>
        <li class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Autobusy </li>
        <li class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Prodej ojetých vozů  </li>
        <li class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Komponenty   </li>
        <li class="small" data-value="option7" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked/>&nbsp;Alternativní pohony  </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```